# Django form post not getting values in request.GET

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to pass a value to my view using a form as follows,

I have the following form:

```
<form action="{% url 'searchlocation' %}" method="get">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search_location" placeholder="Search">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</form>
```

and in my view i have:

```
def SearchLocation(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        keyword = request.GET.get('search_location','')
        print keyword

    return render_to_response('app/location.html', {'user': request.user}, RequestContext(request))
```

I am not getting any value for keyword here. It just gives me a `''`.

When i tried request.GET['search_location'], it gave me a `multivaluedict error.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must supply a `name` for your form input in order for it to be sent by the browser, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="search_location" class="form-control" id="search_location" placeholder="Search">
```

Request data is sent in the form of a key/value pair. With no `name` attribute, there is no key for the value and the input is not sent by the browser.